# Why is reference not passed

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass a field reference to my method while an event is fired, but the reference is not passed because my field has the same value.

Here is my code:

```
private uint _myNumberField;

private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    HandleTextBoxChanged(sender, _myNumberField);
}

private void HandleTextBoxChanged(object textBoxObject, uint myNumber)
{
    var textBox = textBoxObject as TextBox;

    if (textBox == null)
        return;

    myNumber = 123;
}
```

After firing the `TextBox_OnTextChanged` event the field `_myNumberField` should have the value 123 but has the value 0.

Comment: Because an uint is a value type not a reference type.

Comment: `myInt` isn´t pased by reference but my value.

Comment: @Steve That would not work for reference-types as well, as OP assigns a **new** value, not just modifying the provided instance.

Comment: Is that WinForms or WPF?

Comment: where did you set `_myNumberField`  value to `123`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is there another solution to pass the reference? @Fildor: WPF

Comment: Then the answer is probably: MVVM. Don't do it like this at all. Use Binding and a Model.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ref` keyword:

```
private uint _myNumberField;

private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    HandleTextBoxChanged(sender, ref _myNumberField);
}

private void HandleTextBoxChanged(object textBoxObject, ref uint myNumber)
{
    var textBox = textBoxObject as TextBox;

    if (textBox == null)
        return;

    myNumber = 123;
}
```

Make sure to use `ref` on the caller as well, before specifying the name of the field. For more information on how to use `ref`, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Like others already said, this is not the best approach. But to answer your question, in C# you need to use `ref` when you are dealing with value types and want to pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `myInt` as **reference**, not as **value**, which is done using the `ref`-keyword on your delegate:

```
delegate void HandleTextBoxChanged(object, ref uint);
```

But wouldn´t it be better to directly update `_myNumberField` within `HandleTextBoxChanged` in the first place?